# When doing a page preprocess, how do you know if the page is a form?

Tags: theming, forms

When doing a preprocess on a page (I need to conditionally change something at the page template level) is there a way to tell if the page is going to render a form? The xdebug output didn't show any variables that would tell me this in an obvious way.

Comment: A page can't be a form. A page can contain a form. But we don't know how this form (what form?) got there. So, impossible to tell. You need to share more info/context. Maybe target the node ID or route name.

Comment: It could be many forms. Or any form. The login page, user registration, user editing, etc. This line exists in the page template: {% set container = theme.settings.fluid_container ? 'container-fluid' : 'container' %} so usually the container-fluid class is applied. But I don't like how it looks on forms, so I'd rather apply the container class.

Comment: If your form is block, check existence of this block on the page. If it's in $page, check your URL.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if Drupal preprocess functions doesnt gives you what you are looking for, it probably means that you are not preprocessing the appropriate element. And considering a form would be part of a region (region content?) this rule seems to be appropriate in your care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wanted to apply a change to the page.html.twig template based on if it was a form, I looked first for the form suggestions I was given. Since I couldn't find a way to generically apply a template to all forms, I instead created a template that I would then tell all of the forms that I have to use this template. I used a hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter to add my new template and check the existing suggestions to see if the forms I want to use are part of the current suggestions:

```
function listed_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $forms = [
    'page__user__register',
    'page__admin__people',
  ];
  foreach ($forms as $form) {
    if (in_array($form, $suggestions)) {
      $suggestions[] = 'page__forms';
    }
  }
}
```

From here, I can add additional forms as they are needed to use this single template. So, this solution doesn't exactly answer my original question, but it solves my original problem.